# How to prove these apparent properties of reverse-and-add trajectories?

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems

The base-$b$ [*reverse-and-add*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reverse-Then-AddSequence.html) map, for integers $b\ge 2$ and $n\ge 1$,  is $$f_b:\ \ n\ \mapsto\ \  n\ +\ \text{rev}_b(n),$$ 
where $\text{rev}_b(n)$ is the number obtained by reversing the order of digits in the base-$b$ numeral for $n$. The base-$b$ *trajectory* of $n$ is the sequence of *iterates* $(n, f_b(n), f_b(f_b(n)), f_b(f_b(f_b(n))),\ldots)$.

**NB**: For each $b$ and $n$, successive iterates always increase in value, and their "lengths" (i.e., number of digits) either stay the same or increase by exactly one; that is, every *length-increment* is in $\{0,1\}.$

Examples are in the following picture, which shows the first $50$ iterates in the base-$2$ and base-$10$ trajectories of $n=1$, with the length-increments in a column to the right of each:
[image: base-2 and base-10 trajectories of n=1]

For each of the above trajectories, the first occurrence of the *maximum* observed number of consecutive length-increments equal to $0$ (resp. $1$) is marked in blue (resp. red). In all of my computations$^*$ *all* iterates of *all* starting values exhibit behavior consistent with the following **conjectures**:

1. For each $b$ and $n$, over the entire base-$b$ trajectory of $n$ there is a finite maximum number of consecutive length-increments equal to $0$ (resp. $1$), which will be denoted by $M_{0,b,n}$ (resp. $M_{1,b,n}$). E.g., as in the picture, $M_{0,2,1}=1,M_{1,2,1}=5, M_{0,10,1}=4, M_{1,10,1}=3$.
2. For each $b$, over all possible trajectories (i.e. all $n$) a finite maximum is attained on each set of the two maxima defined in (1); i.e., the following are finite maxima: $$M_{0,b} := max\{M_{0,b,n}: n=1,2,...\},\\M_{1,b} := max\{M_{1,b,n}: n=1,2,...\}.$$
   That is, over all possible base-$b$ trajectories, $M_{0,b}$ (resp. $M_{1,b}$) is the maximum number of consecutive length-increments equal to $0$ (resp. $1$).
3. $M_{0,b}$ and $M_{1,b}$ are the following surprisingly simple functions of $b$:

$$\begin{align}
M_{0,b} &= \lceil log_2(b)\rceil=\text{ number of base-}2\text{ digits in }(b-1)\\
M_{1,b} &= (\text{if }b=2\text{ then }5\text{ else }3)
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c||c|}\hline \text{base, }b & M_{0,b} & M_{1,b}\\
\hline
2&1&5\\
3,4&2&3\\
5,6,7,8&3&3\\
9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16&4&3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
2^{k-1}+1,...,2^{k}&k&3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$^*$ E.g., for each $b\in\{2,3,...,36\}$, the maxima were computed using $10^4$ base-$b$ iterates of each of $10^3$ starting values sampled from $\{1,...,10^{10}\}$. Some trajectories were computed to $10^6$ iterates.

**Questions**:

1. How to prove or disprove any of these conjectures, especially the formulas for $M_{0,b}, M_{1,b}$?
2. Is it not peculiar that $M_{0,b}$ (a function of $b$) should be described by a base-$2$ logarithm? Why should powers of $2$ enter in this way?
3. Is it plausible that $M_{1,b}$ is *constant* for all $b\gt 2$? Why the value of $3$? And what makes base $2$ the exception?